# Objects in array odd behavior

Tags: php, arrays, object

first some code, then the problem

```
$squad_ids = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM squad WHERE owner=$owner_id");

include "squads.php";
$squads = array();
$squads_num = 0;

foreach ($squad_ids as $squad_id){
    $squads[$squads_num] = new Squad($squad_id["id"]);
    var_dump($squads[$squads_num]); // <-------------- DUMP 1
    $squads_num++;
}
...
foreach ($squads as $squad){
    var_dump($squad); // <-------------- DUMP 2
}
```

So what I do is to fill the `$squads` array with `Squad` objects (two at the tests).
When dumping the array field (`DUMP 1`) everything is just fine, both objects are shown.

After that I'm looping through the created `$squads` array and want to access the stored objects.

But for some odd reason it's both times the exactly same object. When dumping `$squad` (`DUMP 2`) it shows exactly the same for both iterations in the test (it's the second objects both times).

I can't explain that.

---

(Actually there IS code between these two foreach loops, but it hasn't anything to do with `$squads`.)

For reference, the class:

```
class Squad {
    private $mysqli;
    private $squad = array(
        "id"=>null,
        "name"=>null,
        "owner"=>null,
        "battlefield"=>null,
        "posx"=>null,
        "posy"=>null,
        "radius"=>null,
        "action"=>null,
        "action_cmd"=>null
        );
    private $map = array();
    private $scan = array();

    function Squad($id){
        global $squad;
        global $mysqli;

        include "db_connect.php";

        $squad_request_raw = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM squad WHERE id = '$id'");
        $squad_request = $squad_request_raw->fetch_object();

        $squad["id"] = $squad_request->id;
        $squad["name"] = $squad_request->name;
        $squad["owner"] = $squad_request->owner;
        $squad["battlefield"] = $squad_request->battlefield;
        $squad["posx"] = $squad_request->posx;
        $squad["posy"] = $squad_request->posy;
        $squad["radius"] = $squad_request->radius;
        $squad["action"] = $squad_request->action;
        $squad["action_cmd"] = $squad_request->action_cmd;
    }

    function getId(){
        global $squad;
        return $squad["id"];
    }
}
```

Comment: This code seems to be fine at first sight, but the ellipsis halfway seem to suggest that there is more. Maybe the omitted code modifies the array? It must be.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/KqgqPfFL)

Comment: One thing to watch out for, that can cause similar oddities is if you are using any `&$referenced` variables -- in terms of `&$squads`, `&squad_id` or `&$squad` at any point prior to this code (or at the ellipsis) and do not correctly `unset` them before reusing the variable. If you could update your question with the contents of `$squad_ids` that would also be of use in debugging the problem...

Comment: _“Actually there IS code between these two foreach loops, but it hasn't anything to do with $squads”_ – fine, then take _all_ of that code out – the problem should still persist then, if you are correct …

Comment: Using `$squads_num` is superfluous, btw. – simply use `$squads[] =` instead to create new array entries with an automatic numerical index.

Comment: @pebbl: updated it, they come from a mysql query

Comment: @CBroe: Did that, and yes it persists, that's why I left it out.

Comment: By "contents of `$squad_ids`" I meant the data in the array. Also shouldn't `$mysqli->query` be followed by some form of `fetch` in order to get multiple rows? I've not really used `mysqli` more `pdo` so just checking, the documentation would suggest that is required... if it is, then what is likely occurring is that you are stepping the `id` field twice, once as an assoc key and once as a numerical key... each time the `id` will be the same because the result is for the same row (rather than multiple rows). http://uk.php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: Ah, sry. Misunderstood then. But it's correct as it is. As said I **do** get the correct objects into the array in the first loop. It's so strange, now I removed nearly every code from the class either,... still the problem exists.

Comment: @HelloImNewHere Something is messing with the array in the part you aren't posting

Comment: It doesn't matter what's there, as the problem persists even when I delete that part. So it's exaclty the same as shown here. For reference I added the class, dunno what more to do.

Comment: You should remove your `global $squad;` lines... they are what is causing the issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely remove these lines:

`global $squad;`

From within your class. I can't set the code up to test at the moment, but that will definitely be causing strange things to occur... as that is the same var you are using in your foreach and in each instance of your class. All global vars in php work from the very base level of the code, so every instance will be using the same var... plus I don't see why your class requires this var to be global anyway.

As you are using `var_dump` immediately after each class instance is created in the first loop, they will look fine for the lifetime of each loop iteration. But because you are globalising the internal variable used by your class, each time an instance is created you will be modifying the same var/structure, especially as you aren't redefining the array in the constructor method. I actually don't think your class will even be using your private `$this->squad` array at all *(although it may be globalising this, I can't tell without testing)*. I bet if you always `var_dump` only the first item in the array — in your first `foreach` — you will see that it changes as the loop progresses. i.e. try this:

```
foreach ($squad_ids as $squad_id){
  $squads[$squads_num] = new Squad($squad_id["id"]);
  var_dump($squads[0]); // <-------------- DUMP 1
  $squads_num++;
}
```

You will probably see that `$squads[0]` will become the same as `$squads[1]` after `$squads[1]` has been created, and so on... Globalising the `$squad` var is effectively causing it to act the same as a `&reference`.

Comment: You are **the man**! I rewrote my class, using `$this->squad = (); $this->squad["id"] = ...` now... seems to work just fine.

Comment: @HelloImNewHere ~ no worries, glad I could help. Reference issues will always send you a little bonkers as it appears that magic is happening :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue in your code, but I would also try setting the key in your loop and see what's been printed:

```
foreach ($squads as $key => $squad){
    var_dump($squads[$key]); 
}
```